# (Rails) Is there a way to check the field's datatype?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you check what the datatype is for something that was retrieved from the database?

For example, if I have some instantiation of a model @model with a database field "title", I want to be able to code something like @model.title.type and have it return "String". Does Rails have any built-in functionality for this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this:

```
@model.column_for_attribute('title').type
```

Should return `:string`, `:text`, `:integer`, etc.

The ActiveRecord [Column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Column.html) class also includes a number of other attributes: default, limit, name, null, precision, primary, scale, sql_type, type.

Comment: Note also has: name, precision, primary, null, limit and default

Answer (score 14):

In Rails 3, for my model "Firm", I'd use `Firm.columns_hash`.

```
Firm.columns_hash["name"].type  #returns :string
```

If you want to iterate through them, you'd do something like this:

```
Firm.columns_hash.each {|k,v| puts "#{k} => #{v.type}"}
```

which will output the following:

```
id => integer
name => string
max_trade_qty => integer
```

and so on.