# Rails 4 how to find the maximum length of a string column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

To find the maximum length of string column in SQL is:

```
select max(length(<column>)) from <table>
```

Can anyone show how to do the same in Rails 4 activerecord or even squeel?

Comment: For the actual length limit on a string field (rather than the longest value), check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257658/rails-is-there-a-way-to-check-the-fields-datatype

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Model.pluck("max(length(column))")`, which won't load everything into memory.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
Model.pluck(:column).max_by(&:length)

#=> will return the longest string
```

Another option would be to just execute a query in SQL:

```rb
Model.connection.execute("SELECT MAX(LENGTH(column)) FROM my_table")
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey. However, I was seeking to hand the query off to the sql server to avoid pulling in all of the rows which I think your suggestion will do unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Ross you are right - accepted solution is more(most) efficient one.